Can I define a field in a django model to return data from another model that meets certain conditions?
I have a model for recipes. I have a model for reviews of those recipes. The recipe's author (chef) can select a specific review as their favorite. I think I've set the constraint up correctly to only allow one favorite review per recipe. Let's assume one favorite review per recipe.
I would like to reference the one favorite review using the recipe model. Is this possible? Example template snippet below.
{% for recipe in recipes %}
<div>
  <h2>{{ recipe.name }}</h2>
  <p>{{ recipe.favoriteReview.content }} <small>by {{ recipe.favoriteReview.author }}</small></p>
  <p>Email the chef: {{ recipe.chef.email }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}

Here's an example of the models but I feel like I've approached this from the wrong direction and I've hit a wall.
# Models as example
class User(AbstractUser):
  pass

class Recipe(models.model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  instructions = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
  chef = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="recipes")
 #favoriteReview = The review with chefsFavorite=True and recipe matches this recipe

class Review(models.model):
  author = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="reviews")
  rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2)
  content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
  chefsFavorite = models.Boolean(default="True")
  recipe = models.ForeignKey("Recipe", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="recipes")

  class Meta:
    constraints = [
      models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['recipe'], condition=models.Q(chefsFavorite=True), name="chefs_one_favorite_recipe_review"
    ]


From your code at a glance, it looks largely on the right track. If it does not work, please describe how your app actually does behave and any errors you're encountering.

@Vegard I don't know how to implement recipe.favoriteReview. In my model above it's commented out to illustrate what I would like to accomplish.  Thanks.

You can have a m2m relation with extra fields and set the constraints there:
models.py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...


class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="ChefsFavoriteReview")


class ChefsFavoriteReview(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="favorite_reviews"
    )
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["user", "recipe"], name="chefs_one_favorite_recipe_review"
            )
        ]

A brief example:
views.py
def favorites(request):
    favorites = (
        get_user_model().objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
        .favorite_reviews.all()
    )
    return render(request, "favorites.html", {"favorites": favorites})

favorites.html
<body>
{{request.user.name}}
{% for obj in favorites %}
<div>
    <h2>Recipe: {{obj.recipe.name}}</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>
    {{obj.review.author}} says "{{obj.review.content}}" and gives this
    recipe a rating of {{obj.review.rating}}
    </p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</body>


Thanks for the insight! I like it, but it wouldn't return recipes where a chef hasn't picked a favorite, would it? Additionally, do you think this would be a good candidate for inheritance. class ChefsFavoriteReview(Review): chef = modes.ForeignKey("user"...?

No it wouldn't, for that you have to filter all the recipes and exclude the ones the chef has votes on. You can easily do that by retrieving recipes PKs from the new table.

As for the inheritance, its not suitable. You would be bringing useless fields into the relation.

Hypothetically, the inheritance happens in case where the Recipe is the base for a MainDishRecipe(Recipe)or a DessertRecipe(Recipe) where these two would have different extra processes.

You're probably right about inheritance, but my initial reaction was that a favoriteReview was just a review with the addition of a chef field. Thanks for the examples, I'll need to think on that some more to understand it better.

The difference lies in the Review, whether this object can be liked by more than one chef.
